# Dynamic link in Django always calls the first url path

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

In urls.py within `urlpatterns` I have below two lines

```
urlspatterns = [
...
path('<slug:productSlug>', ProductView.as_view(), name = 'viewProduct'),
path('<slug:boxSlug>', BoxView.as_view(), name = 'BoxView'),
...
]
```

In my html template I have two links

```
<a href="{% url 'viewProduct' item.productSlug %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true">product view</a>

<a href="{% url 'BoxView' item.boxSlug %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true">Box View</a>
```

The problem is even though I specified BoxView in the `{% url 'BoxView' ... %}` it keeps calling the `viewProduct` path. If I reverse the order of the two paths in urlPatterns then, it keeps calling the 'BoxView'. What I don't understand is it keeps calling whatever it finds first in `urlPatterns`.

Comment: The two paths are fully overlapping, hence it will *always* trigger the first path. You need to make them non-overlapping, for example by adding a different prefix to both URLs

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understands. In {% url 'BoxView'....%} isn't it supposed to called the path with the name 'BoxView' and in {% url 'viewProduct' %} isn't it supposed to call the path with name 'viewProduct'?

Comment: it will translate to a URL. But every URL constructed by both of these will trigger the first URL path that matches, in this case the `ProductView`.

Comment: Thanks for detailing this. Should url prefix be added in urlPatterns? Can you demonstrate an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You something to distingish between the view type. For example you could:

```
urlspatterns = [
...
path('product_view/<slug:productSlug>', ProductView.as_view(), name = 'viewProduct'),
path('box_view/<slug:boxSlug>', BoxView.as_view(), name = 'BoxView'),
...
]
```